# How to store floats in array to be used later?

Tags: c, arrays

how can a user of a program store info in arrays such as a float number and can be calculated for an average later in the program? im trying to make a program to calculate someones grade point average.

Comment: No need to store individual elements; just sum up the values and keep track of how many there are, then divide at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
int maxGrades = 50; // pick this
int numGrades = 0;

float[] grades = malloc (sizeof (float) * maxGrades);


// in a loop somewhere
if(numGrades == maxGrades) {
  maxGrades *= 2;
  float[] newGrades = malloc (sizeof (float) * maxGrades);
  for(int i = 0; i < numGrades; i++) newGrades[i] = grades[i];
  grades = newGrades;
}
grades[numGrades++] = theNewestGrade;
```

Comment: Remember to free that memory (this program will probably end after this but it is good practice).

Comment: Please provide code that compiles. And what's your question? Your code stores floats in arrays (although mostly it stores undefined values from grades into newgrades -- better done by memcpy) so you apparently know how to do that.

Comment: Hey I'll be straight up, I'm a Java guy. I was just illustrating the basic principles I would use to store the data in an array. Users of sufficient reputation are welcome to edit to remove inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

Transitting from java to C, the biggest "concept jump" you have to make is Pointers.

Try allocating your floats this way:

```
float *float_array = malloc(amount_of_elemts_in_array * sizeof(float))
```

You can then iterate through using

```
float_array[index]
```

Having this pointer will enable you to pass `float_array` in and out of functions by reference which is a great convenience since you don't want to recreate instances over every function call.

Pass `float_array` into functions using:

```
Function Declaration: void function_that_uses_float_array(float *placeholder);
Function Call: function_that_uses_float_array(placeholder);
```

Pass `float_array` out of functions using:

```
Return statement: return a_float_pointer;
One level up the stack: float_array = function_that_returns_a_float_pointer();
```

Arrays are automatically passed by reference.

Hope this helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: sorry, I was reading the other answer with Java, that's why I thought the person who asked the question was transitting from Java. Disregard the first line if you're not coming from Java :)