# How to extract digits after decimal point in float and store in char Array

Tags: c, arrays

I refered below question but I need to extract the digits after decimal and store in `char *array`

1.[How to store float in array of float[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011861/how-to-store-floats-in-array-to-be-used-later)

2.[Extract digits in float in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886402/how-to-get-numbers-after-decimal-point)

**Ex:**

```
 float = 1.24456
```

My length of `char *array` is 2

**Expected Output:**

```
array[0] = 2;
array[1] = 4;
array[2] = 4;
```

I need to implement this in C dynamically.

Comment: `snprintf()` the number to a string.

Comment: If the value was very close, but less than `1.244`, like `1.243999`, would you want `243` or `244`?

Comment: @coder `1.24456` cannot be exactly represent by most `float`, Then the best approach differs, if you want 3 digits from the exact value of the `float` or one rounded to 3 decimal places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can isolate the fractional part of a `float` by using the function `modff` in `<math.h>`, which returns the fractional part as the function's return value and the whole-number part as an argument by reference:

```
float f = 3.141592f;
float numpart, fracpart;
fracpart = modff(f, &numpart);
```

Once you're done that, you can create a string with a conventional string-building function:

```
char buf[100];
snprintf(buf, 100, "%f", fracpart);
```

Another option is converting the entire `float` to a string, and then using `strchr(float_str, '.')` to isolate the decimal part:

```
char floatbuf[100], decibuf[100], *p;
float f = 3.141592f;

snprintf(floatbuf, 100, "%f", f);
if ((p = strchr(floatbuf, '.')) != NULL)
{
    strcpy(decibuf, p + 1);
    puts(decibuf);
}
```

Comment: "converting the entire float to a string," --> may need a fairly long string, easily more than 20.

Comment: @chux Do you know off hand how many digits are storable in a 32-bit `float`?

Comment: Typically 24 significant binary digits.  But I think you are looking for `FLT_MAX_10_EXP`  "maximum integer such that 10 raised to that power is in the range of representable
finite floating-point numbers" - often 37.  Perhaps `char buf[1 + 1 + FLT_MAX_10_EXP + 1 + 6 + 1];` to cope with `-FLT_MAX`.  No need to guess

Comment: Try `printf("%f", -FLT_MAX);`

Comment: @chux Yup - 48 chars.

Comment: Pedantic: note that `strchr(float_str, '.')` will return `NULL` with infinity/NaN.

Comment: @chux Correct, but failing to check the return value of `strchr` for `NULL`, regardless of input, is bad coding

Comment: Note: If the factional part if used as in `snprintf(buf, 100, "%f", fracpart);`, 9 should be enough: `"-.xxxxxx"` or less in OP's case of `char *array is 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more mathematical approach, but arguably less flexible would be this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float num = 1.24456;
    int num_noDecimals = (int)num; //truncate decimals in original number
    float num_onlyDecimals = num - (float)num_noDecimals; //obtain only the number after decimal
    int x = 4; //number of digits past decimal to extract
    num_onlyDecimals = num_onlyDecimals*pow(10,x); //move extracting digits left of decimal
    int digits_forArray = (int)num_onlyDecimals; //truncate remaining digits right of decimal
    char arr[x];
    for(int i=x-1; i > -1; i--) { arr[i] = (char)(digits_forArray%10); digits_forArray = digits_forArray/10; }
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++) { printf("arr[%d] = %d\n",i,arr[i]); }
}
```

Hopefully it's commented well enough to understand the steps being taken here.

Comment: `(int)num` is undefined behavior unless `num` is near the range of `int`.

Answer (score 0):

In my code, I removed the integer part, then I reverse the float part to integer part by multiply each number of the float part by the number 10 then I classify each digit of  in the array

My code :

```
int main()
{
    float n = 1.2445601;
    int m=(int)n;
    float p=n-m;
    int x=7,i=0,tab[x];
    while(i<x)
    {
        p=p*10;
        i++;
    }
    i=6;
    while((int)p!=0)
    {
        tab[i--]=(int)p%10;
        p=p/10;
    }

    for(int k=0;k<x;k++)
    {
         printf("\narray[%d] = %d ;",k,tab[k]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you just want the digits after the decimal point in variable, you could just have number - floor(number)

for example, if your number was 3.25, the calculation would be 3.25 - 3. This will give 0.25

Comment: This answer is just plain wrong, and has nothing to do with the question. I would recommend removing it.